# How can I perform colour and alpha replacements based on colour channel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have extracted texture files from a game that I intend to use in Unity. In doing so, I have one texture map labeled "Multi" that is intended to be overlaid on top of the Diffuse texture. Problem is, I have found few details about "Multi" texture maps online, so I decided I would manually overlay it onto the Diffuse texture itself.

That brings me to my current issue: the Multi texture map has a red background. The foreground transitions from red to yellow, and has certain white spots. As I understand it, everywhere it is red should be transparent. Places where it is yellow should be a colour (we'll denote it A). White areas should be another colour (denoted B). This corresponds pretty neatly with the image's colour channels:

- Red -> Colour A
- Green -> Opacity
- Blue -> Colour B

There is a slight complication in that the Blue channel shouldn't simply represent Colour B directly. Since Red is maxed everywhere Blue is, it should somehow represent the "spectrum" from A to B.

How can I take the image of this texture and convert it as described? I have access to photoshop.

Here is the texture in question.

[image: The "Multi" texture]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. It *sounds* doable, but it's pretty impossible to help without having access to the image. To answer this I would test if the method I had in mind really worked and perhaps illustrate the answer. I can't easily find an image that fits your description and I might misunderstand you. (But there might be a copyright issue - you say you have extracted the image from a game?)

Comment: @Wolff Thank you for the welcome! I've uploaded the image [here.](https://imgur.com/a/besNYp9) Hopefully that'll do.

Comment: If it's yours to share you should edit and add the image to the question itself.

Comment: @Wolff I've edited it as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red channel is *almost* white, but has a slightly grey tone and some details here and there. I'll ignore that here. Some of it might just come from image compression.

- Select the layer with the original image.
- Enter the *Channels* panel.
- Click the *Blue* channel.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to *Select All*.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to *Copy*.
- Click *RGB* to select all channels.
- Enter the *Layers* panel.
- Create a new *Solid Color* layer and select the color you want for the white areas.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click the *Layer Mask* of the *Solid Color* layer to enter it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to *Paste*.
- Click the *Solid Color* layer's icon to exit the mask.
- Turn off the *Solid Color* layer.
- Select the layer with the original image.
- Enter the *Channels* panel.
- Click the *Green* channel.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to *Select All*.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to *Copy*.
- Click *RGB* to select all channels.
- Enter the *Layers* panel.
- Create a new *Solid Color* layer and select the color you want for the yellow areas.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click the *Layer Mask* of the *Solid Color* layer to enter it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to *Paste*.
- Click the *Solid Color* layer's icon to exit the mask.
- Turn off the layer with the original image.
- Turn on the first *Solid Color* layer.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to *Deselect*.

[image]

(The chosen colors can be changed later by double-clicking the icons of the *Solid Color* layers.)